# How do you add UITabBarViewController to an existing UIViewController?

Tags: xcode

currently I've been able to create a UIViewcontroller with a login screen and it pushes nicely to another view, now I've changed my mind about how the apps going to look and I basically want to push it to a tab bar view. Whats the best way of going about this?

I thought that tabbar works only with the appdelegate? so i tried applying it to the current mainview.xib as well and tried to switch to the Tabbarviewcontroller after the user logs in correctly. Now either thats retarded or I'm not doing it right at all?

any help will be appreciated.

Mark P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach might be to go ahead and make the UITabBarViewController your main viewController, and to display the login screen modally upon app startup or on app resumption (depending on your rules for login timeout).

Comment: Cheers for the tip, I was able to figure a way out however after a day of fiddling with new views I was able to input one myself that has a similar structure to the basic tab-bar structure template apple gives, however doing a little tweeking to link it up to react to a correct login.

Basically it's what I did before I posted on here apart from I forgot to include a window and use that as an object to link the tabbarcontroller to the the app as the tabbarcontroller isn't a view which can be selected.

Thanks though!